# PHP file upload only retaining extension

Tags: php, html, file-upload, ftp

For my website, I have a PHP image file upload system so that users can upload their own pictures. Those pictures are stored in `/images/`, and I have changed its file permission to `777` . When I test the upload file, it works but the file only keeps the `.jpg` extension and not the prefix:

```
<?php
$name= 'filename';
$newname= '/images/'. $name. '.jpg';
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

    $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");         
    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
    }
    /*if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }*/             
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        rename($file_tmp, $newname);
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>`
```

Comment: Read the manual on `rename()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php and look at the first example under **User Contributed Notes**.

Comment: You also tagged as [`ftp`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ftp) but fail to see the relevance here.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually seen [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) before, but just trying it, I'll admit its behavior doesn't seem to be quite what I expect. Try [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) instead.

Most importantly, I notice you were checking that the only image formats you accepted were `png` and `jpeg`, yet you were renaming them all to `jpg`. Why? Not all image viewers will open a `png` with a `jpg` extension.

```
<?php
$name= 'filename';
$newname= '/images/'. $name;//. '.jpg'; // why wouldn't you preserve the correct extension? i.e. $file_ext
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

    $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");         
    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
    }
    /*if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }*/             
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        // // // use move_uploaded_file() instead // // //
        //rename($file_tmp, $newname);
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$newname.$file_ext");
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes but that doesn't solve my problem: The filename only keeps the extension (whether its `.jpg` or `.png`)

Comment: Hmm, then there must be a problem with the way you're assigning `$name` because this script works as is.